# VC dimension of an oriented hyperplane

Tags: classifying-spaces

What is VC dimension (Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension) of an oriented hyperplane? I know that VC dimension of set of oriented hyperplanes is $n+1$. Is it the same? I came across this question recently... I know VC dimensions of several algorithms but not sure how to apply this to hyperplanes. Thanks!

Comment: What would be an example of a *nonoriented* hyperplane?